# Force to open link in browser for fallback

Tags: android

I have an intent-filter that open all links with host "xyzxyz.com/value".

In the manifest I set an Activity to receive it:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ui.LinkOpenerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="xyzxyz.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So when the user click on a "xyzxyz.com/value" link it open the app, that execute certain operations based on the "value" in the URL.

What I would like to do is to open the default browser in case the "value" have an incorrect value.

I tried with

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlReceivedFromIntent));
```

startActivity(browserIntent);

but it end up in an infinite loop, because it open again my app... any suggestion to fallback in the default browser and open http://xyzxyz.com/value in it?

---

Solved with Intent chooser:

```
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(
            Intent.createChooser(browserIntent, null)
    );
    finish();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) you can get the list of the activities that are able to resolve your intent. You can then filter out yours and pick another one explicitly by using [Intent.setClassName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29) (or force a chooser by using [Intent.createChooser](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html))

Comment: if you have set a default intent, then queryIntentActivities won't return all the activities list on Marshmallow and above. A bug in the API